# How to convert an integer method to boolean in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

let me explain better. I am creating a CRUD project in Spring MVC; as I am making some changes to the code, initially the method of interest was integer type. I put the code below for you to understand better.

```js
public int delete(int studentId) {
        String sql = "delete from student1 where stu_id=?";

        try {

            int counter = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { studentId });

            return counter;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Now I have to create it as a boolean.
I tried to do it in the following way:

```js
public boolean delete(int studentId) {
        String sql = "delete from student1 where stu_id=?";

        boolean status=false;

        try {

            status = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { studentId });

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return status;
        }
    }
```

it just gives me an error on

jdbcTemplate.update (sql, new Object [] {studentId})

because jdbcTemplate.update returns an integer.
How can I change this?
Thank you all

Comment: Well, you WANT that a method that returns a number is "reduced" to a true/false result. You WANT that. So YOU should know what nubmers should result in true, and what should lead to false. That is all there is to this, you know, like `if (theNumber == 42) return true else false` or something like that. We cant tell you what you think constitutes a "true" number, and what should be "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not convert int to boolean directly but we can say that if the integer value is greater than equal to 1  set the boolean value as true, otherwise set boolean as false.
**For an int, any non-zero value evaluates to true, while zero evaluates to false.**
Also `jdbcTemplate.update()` returns an `int` not a `boolean` value , 1 if query was successful otherwise 0.

You can try it like this

```
public boolean delete(int studentId) {
        String sql = "delete from student1 where stu_id=?";

       
        boolean statusFlag = true;
        
        int status = 0;

        try {

            status = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { studentId });

            if(status >= 1 || status < 0){
                statusFlag = true;
            }
            else{
                statusFlag = false;
            }
            
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        return statusFlag;
    }
}
```

Or a simpler way

```
return status !=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
public boolean delete(int studentId) {
        String sql = "delete from student1 where stu_id=?";

        int status;

        try {

            status = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { studentId });

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status != 0;
    }
```

This is the simplest way.  "return status != 0;"  I also moved the return statement out of the catch block so that the method always has a return statement.